# getItemIdAtPosition() in listview not showing

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I need to get getItemIdAtPosition() from listView to get the id of the records from sqlite database. When i click on the listView on any item, it always shows "null" not showing the id.

this is the code:

```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

               int id= ((int) listView.getItemIdAtPosition(i));

                //create our intent, as per usual
                Intent intent=new Intent(Tutorial10.this, Activity2.class);

                intent.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{

String passedVar=null;
private TextView passedView=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act2);

    //Get our passed variable from our intent's EXTRAS
    passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra(Tutorial10.ID_EXTRA);
    //find out text view
    passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passed);
    //display our passed variable!!!
    passedView.setText("YOU CLICKED ON="+passedVar);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line

```
  int id= ((int) listView.getItemIdAtPosition(i));
```

with this

```
  long id = adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
```

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks for Answer. I used your solution. It shows no error. But when i click any item, it shows the same result "null"

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android official document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView#getItemIdAtPosition(int)), there's no definition about the purpose of this function. It seems to call to [getItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)) in Adapter, and getItemId() returns the value of Id in SQLite.

I guess you need to use [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter) to work with the SQLite.